# Re-organizing SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I am new to Stored Procedure.
This below stored procedure is trying to get Meeting attachment publisher details.
I am passing **meeting_id** as **parameter** and from **meetingPublish Table** I am getting the **Publisher UserId**. using that I want to **retrive** EmployeeID, UserName, BranchName, DepartmentName, Desugnation etc from Table **EmployeeInfo,Department, Designation, ULC Branch.**

> **Problem with this stored procedure is that it only returns the Last Publisher Details. How can I change this in a way that I can get all
> the Publisher Details under a MeetingID.**

```
USE [Intranet]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [MeetingManagement].[prGetMeetingMakerDetailsByMeetingId]    Script Date: 5/25/2023 5:08:34 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [MeetingManagement].[prGetMeetingMakerDetailsByMeetingId] 
(
    @MeetingId int
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @UserId NVARCHAR(50);


    SELECT @UserId = m.PublishBy 
    FROM MeetingManagement.MeetingPublish m
     WHERE m.MeetingId = @MeetingId

    Select E.UserID AS UserId , e.EmployeeName +'('+e.EmpCode+')' as EmployeeName,e.EmployeeID,
    g.DesignationName,d.DeptName,b.ULCBranchName,e.MobileNo,e.Photos,e.MailAddress,
    se.EmployeeName+'('+se.EmpCode+')' CurrentSupervisor,
    se.MailAddress as CurrentSupervisormail,
    se.UserID as SupervisorId
    
    from [SharedData].EmployeeInfo e
    INNER JOIN SharedData.Department d on e.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID
    INNER JOIN SharedData.Designation g on e.DesignationID = g.DesignationID
    inner join SharedData.ULCBranch b on e.ULCBranchID = b.ULCBranchID
    LEFT JOIN [SharedData].EmployeeInfo se ON se.EmployeeID = e.CurrentSupervisor
    where e.isActive=1
    and e.UserID = @UserId
    and e.EmployeeName not like '%N\A%'
    and e.EmployeeName not like '%Ex-%'
    and e.EmployeeName is not null
    and e.EmpCode is not null 
    ORDER by EmployeeName asc
END
```

Comment: Why have you tagged two different products, tag only the correct RDBMS you are using please.

Comment: Well partly, in your question you state `Mysql` when clearly it's not.

Comment: can't you move the meetingpublish table to a join in your main select? why do you need to fetch @UserId separately

Comment: `JOIN MeetingManagement.MeetingPublish m ON m.MeetingId = e.UserID` also `and e.EmployeeName is not null` is not necessary because of the `NOT LIKE` which already excludes nulls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [MeetingManagement].[prGetMeetingMakerDetailsByMeetingId] 
(
    @MeetingId int
)
AS
BEGIN
--DECLARE @UserId NVARCHAR(50);


    --SELECT @UserId = m.PublishBy 
    --FROM MeetingManagement.MeetingPublish m
    -- WHERE m.MeetingId = @MeetingId

    Select E.UserID AS UserId , e.EmployeeName +'('+e.EmpCode+')' as EmployeeName,e.EmployeeID,
    g.DesignationName,d.DeptName,b.ULCBranchName,e.MobileNo,e.Photos,e.MailAddress,
    se.EmployeeName+'('+se.EmpCode+')' CurrentSupervisor,
    se.MailAddress as CurrentSupervisormail,
    se.UserID as SupervisorId
    
    from [SharedData].EmployeeInfo e
    INNER JOIN SharedData.Department d on e.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID
    INNER JOIN SharedData.Designation g on e.DesignationID = g.DesignationID
    inner join SharedData.ULCBranch b on e.ULCBranchID = b.ULCBranchID
    LEFT JOIN [SharedData].EmployeeInfo se ON se.EmployeeID = e.CurrentSupervisor
    where e.isActive=1
    --and e.UserID = @UserId
    AND EXISTS (    SELECT 1 
                    FROM MeetingManagement.MeetingPublish m
                    WHERE m.MeetingId = @MeetingId
                    AND e.UserID = m.PublishBy
                )
    and e.EmployeeName not like '%N\A%'
    and e.EmployeeName not like '%Ex-%'
    and e.EmployeeName is not null
    and e.EmpCode is not null 
    ORDER by EmployeeName asc
END
```

Comment: Code only answer with no explanation from high rep user - what nonsense is this?